# How to convert key pair from binary file to text file?

Tags: gnupg

I have a gpg keypair (2048 RSA) in binary file: a.pub and a.sec, now I want to convert it to text format, how to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a text/ASCII dump (armored output) of the public key, '`gpg --export -a`'.
Read up [GnuPG](http://www.linuxchick.org/gpg/outline.html) for more.
Also see, Linux Journal [GnuPG Hacks](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8732).

Answer (score 17):

To convert the keys without importing them:

> To wrap a file in PGP ASCII armor, type:
>
> `$ gpg --enarmor < filename.bin > filename.txt`
>
> To unwrap a file already in PGP ASCII armor, type:
>
> `$ gpg --dearmor < filename.txt > filename.bin`

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8732 (thanks to @nik)